# Calls to multiple functions in document ready

Tags: jquery

I have multiple functions inside document ready. All being called with ids click function.

```
$(function(){
  $('#show').click(function(){
    //do something
  });
  $('#cancel').click(function(){
    //do something
  });
  $('#send').click(function(){
    //do something
  });
});
```

In the #show I create the an element where the #cancel and #send ids are created. But nothing happens when they're clicked on nor any errors come up when debugging.

Inside #show I wrote all the HTML in a variable and then just used .append to put it in place.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you create `#cancel` and `#send` when you click on `#show`, so you should bind the click event inside #show event and after the creation of elements like this:

`$(function(){
  $('#show').click(function(){
    //do something
 // Element '#cancel' and '#send' creation
   $('#cancel').click(function(){
  //do something
   });
   $('#send').click(function(){
  //do something
   });
  });
});`

Comment: put the cancel and send click functions inside the show click function

Comment: A fiddle would be helpful. If you are building the elements dynamically you may have to add [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) when creating the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) say: **Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to `.on()`** (and `click(...)` is just a shortcut for `on('click',...)`

One way to deal with this is delegated events, described there.  In your case it could be something like:

```
$(function(){
  $('#show').click(function(){
    //do something
  });
  $('body').on('click', '#cancel', function(){
    //do something
  });
  $('body').on('click', '#send', function(){
    //do something
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing it out. I thought the call for .on() would be on the actual event trigger (the click/tap or whatever).